# how to build an angularJS wysiwyg editor

Tags: angularjs

I am currently trying to figure out how i can make a basic wysiwyg.
I do not know angularJS this is an exercise in order to learn it.
I am trying to get the concept of a wysiwyg editor right.
I assume i will have an invisible textarea that will bind to a differnt div its content after parsing.
The text area will save it content with fake tags and stuff for examle [bold, style:my style, codeblock,]text[end]

And i will parse it to a differnt div that when i select text it the div it will really select text in the textarea.

1. Do i have the concept right?
2. Is there a better way to do it
3. Is it possible to do with plane angluar? Because i think angular cant manipulate the dom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular uses Jquery.  Actually it has it's own version of Jquery called JQLite built in to it but if you add JQuery to your page, it dumps the internal and uses your JQuery version.  Just be sure to reference the JQuery file first.

**Issues with Angular and DOM Manipulation**

Dom Manipulation is rather easy with JQuery.  Angular is a very powerful SPA (Single Page Application) framework.  The problem is that Angular runs by using references to elements and by cycling through a loop called a digest cycle updating the page as needed.  The issue is that if you simply use JQuery to manipulate the DOM, you are doing this outside of the Angular cycles, breaking references and crashing your page.

**Do you want to use Angular**

As angular uses JQuery as it's core, there is no advantage to use Angular at all for DOM.  As a matter of fact it get more difficult but if your application is for handling other data it may be worth it.  The design is completely different though.  In angular, you will need to use directives which are reusable code elements Angular style.

**Design**

I think you have the idea of the concept of the editor.  You pretty much wrap elements in a div tag that allows you to move it other DOM Nodes, Add New Nodes, etc.  That div would be an overlay over your control that provides you to overlay options.  Without specifics, there is not much more I can offer along those lines.

Hope this helps some.

Comment: I read a whole bunch of articles that said i should not use jquery with angular and that 95% of the time you can do everying with angular.

Comment: That is correct.  You should not use JQuery on its own because you need to update the DOM in a way that Angular is aware.  You use Angular which uses JQuery. 
The point I was trying to make is that while you can do it in Angular, JQuery is made for that but if you want all of the complex bindings and data advantages of Angular then it is worth the effort.  DOM manipulation is done through building directives in Angular and done is a very different way that JQuery.